# HTML5 or JAVAFX in terms of GUI design and Performance?

Tags: html, multithreading, performance, javafx-8, web-worker

I want to build a stock trading application, and I'm doing my search to use the best technology that helps me in building this application with great GUI design in addition to the excellent performance, programming languages like C,C++ and Java guarantee performance while GUI design is great in JavaFX and HTML5....

I need to take a decision about that, and till this moment, I have a 65% for JavaFX.

so which one will use and why? and In case you have better options don't hesitate to mention it.

Comment: Java does not guarantee performance. Java is generally not suitable for real-time applications because it uses GC instead of deterministic memory management - which is what I imagine a stock-trading application needs: low-latency UI, smooth with no GC pauses. If you want to do things with the lowest latency and maximum control then use OpenGL from C running on VxWorks.

Comment: Also, "Java" is not capitalised because it is not an acronym, neither is JavaFX.

Comment: I do not agree with @Dai's views on Java/JavaFX not suitable for a real-time application. I agree that Java might not be a suitable choice to create a game-engine but a stock trading software should do just fine. Nevertheless, this question will attract opinion based answers and therefore is not fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha thanks for your comments, I was looking for an expert comparisons between these technologies for such an application.

Comment: @ManKeer Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic